# Comparing different columns to get highest value, and return the rest as NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the dataframe, I want to create 3 new columns labeled as A-hat, B-hat, C-hat, whereby I want to return the highest value by comparing the original column A, B and C, else return as `NaN`. Hence in each of the row, the 3 new column should return two `NaN` and one highest value.

input df:

```
            A         B         C    
Date            
2020-01-05  3.57      5.29      6.23
2020-01-04  4.98      9.64      7.58
2020-01-03  3.79      5.25      6.26
2020-01-02  3.95      5.65      6.61
2020-01-01  -3.10     -7.20     -8.16
```

output df:

```
            A         B         C         A-hat   B-hat   C-hat   
Date            
2020-01-05  3.57      5.29      6.23      NaN     NaN     6.23 
2020-01-04  4.98      9.64      7.58      NaN     9.64    NaN
2020-01-03  3.79      5.25      6.26      NaN     NaN     6.26
2020-01-02  3.95      5.65      6.61      NaN     NaN     6.61
2020-01-01  -3.10     -7.20     -8.16     -3.10   NaN     NaN
```

How can I achieve this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare maximal values by [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) in [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and set missing values by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) if not matched mask:

```
df = df.join(df.where(df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)).add_suffix('-hat'))
print (df)
               A     B     C  A-hat  B-hat  C-hat
Date                                             
2020-01-05  3.57  5.29  6.23    NaN    NaN   6.23
2020-01-04  4.98  9.64  7.58    NaN   9.64    NaN
2020-01-03  3.79  5.25  6.26    NaN    NaN   6.26
2020-01-02  3.95  5.65  6.61    NaN    NaN   6.61
2020-01-01 -3.10 -7.20 -8.16   -3.1    NaN    NaN
```